# redeclare class condition_info

Tags: php, moodle

I upgrade my moodle from 2.6.4 to 2.7.1. After upgrading I've got blank (white) screen. Then I turn on debug display in config.php

```
$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

After that I receive an error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class condition_info in /home/moodle/public_html/lib/conditionlib.php on line 105.

Then I search and found that might be a problem with opcache (https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-45797). So I follow this doc - http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/admin/environment/php_setting/opcache.enable and enable opcache in php.ini:

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 4000
opcache.revalidate_freq = 60

; Required for Moodle
opcache.use_cwd = 1
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.save_comments = 1
opcache.enable_file_override = 0

; If something does not work in Moodle
;opcache.revalidate_path = 1 ; May fix problems with include paths
;opcache.mmap_base = 0x20000000 ; (Windows only) fix OPcache crashes with event id 487

; Experimental for Moodle 2.6 and later
;opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
;opcache.enable_cli = 1 ; Speeds up CLI cron
;opcache.load_comments = 0 ; May lower memory use, might not be compatible with add-ons and other apps.
```

Reload apache and it still doesn't work. I also try to comment out part *; If something does not work in Moodle* and error still occurs. Any idea what might be wrong?

I also read that might be a problem with themes. Before I upgrade I switch theme to Clean which is default theme in 2.7.

I have ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 16:36:58)

Comment: You're redeclaring your class in your php code.

Comment: I didn't change any code in downloaded tar file (moodle-latest-27.tgz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug or an incompatibility with the opcache system.

- i would suggest to turn the opcache off: `opcache.enable = 0`. The opcache is only good, if everything works and you want to gain some additional performance.
- restart PHP
- restart Apache

Finally try one of these downloads:

- 2.7 - https://github.com/moodle/moodle/archive/v2.7.1.tar.gz
- master [latest] - https://github.com/moodle/moodle/archive/master.zip

If the problem persists: please open a new bug report over at moodle and reference the report you found. it is clearly related.

Comment: @repincln Hi, can somebody tell me where to write `opcache.enable = 0` ?

Comment: In your php configuration file: php.ini